# I can't understand the django-markdownx's usage

Tags: python, django, django-templates, markdown

It is kind of embarrassing. But I can't seems to understand [django-markdownx](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx#usage)'s documentation on how to use the app. I've followed the **Getting Started** guide, installed the app and dependencies, added jquery and it works in the Admin backend. But the template doesn't render `text = MarkdownxField()` as correctly formatted markdown, but as plain text.

I don't understand the part ...and then, include a form's required media in the template using `{{ form.media }}`:

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
{{ form.media }}
```

I tried to add that code just before the article tag in my template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    </form>
    {{ form.media }}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ article.text }}</p>
        <div>{{ article.pub_date }} {{ article.category }} {{ article.tag }}</div>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't fix it.

What I'm I missing? I know it is trivial. But I have no experience with forms.

---

**`app/models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='title')
    text = MarkdownxField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='udgivelsesdato')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='kategori', null=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, verbose_name='mærke', null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'artikel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'artikler'
```

**`settings.py`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ***
    'markdownx',
    'articles',
]

# Markdown extensions
MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = [
    'markdown.extensions.sane_lists',
    'markdown.extensions.nl2br',
    'markdown.extensions.extra',
]
```

**`urls.conf`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**`app/urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView

from articles.models import Article
from articles.views import ArticleDetailView, ArticleListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^arkiv/$',
        ArchiveIndexView.as_view(model=Article, date_field="pub_date"),
        name="article_archive"),
    url(r'^$', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_list'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]
```

**`app/templates/app/article_list.html`**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article>
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ article.text }}</p>
    <div>{{ article.pub_date }}</div>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

**`app/views.py`**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from articles.models import Article


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your base file (or somewhere in that template)? If you're in Chrome, press F12 to open the developer console - are there any warnings/errors there? Can you also share your `forms.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did include jQuery in the `base.html`. And it is loading fine. No errors at all in the console... But I have no `forms.py` i just followed the first examples under "Models"... Maybe that is it then? I do need the `forms.py`?

Comment: Hrm - and not necessarily, are you using a generic Django class based view? UpdateView, CreateView, etc? If so, you can share that instead.

Comment: Nope, I just started this project. And the first thing I started working on was the markdown integration. I only have a ListView, DetailView and ArchiveIndexView

Comment: Sounds like that's your issue - can you share your `views.py` then just so I can be sure?

Comment: I added the `views.py` and `app/urls.py`

Comment: It's not you... The docs should be more detailed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I see your issue now (thank you for handling my questions:) ). django-markdownx provides you with the ability to have a Markdown editor inside of your forms. It does not, however, format that markdown when shown in a template - it's just plain text.

According to [this issue on the project's GitHub](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx/issues/25) you need to render the markdown in your views and then pass that to your template. Another way of doing this, which I would prefer if I were using this in a project:

```
from markdownx.utils import markdownify

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='title')
    text = MarkdownxField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='udgivelsesdato')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='kategori', null=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, verbose_name='mærke', null=True)

    # Create a property that returns the markdown instead
    @property
    def formatted_markdown(self):
        return markdownify(self.text)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'artikel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'artikler'
```

then in your template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article>
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ article.formatted_markdown|safe }}</p>
    <div>{{ article.pub_date }}</div>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch that part :) But yes you are right it works, and YES your solution is much more elegant. Thanks... you just have to add `safe` to it. `<p>{{ article.formatted_markdown|safe }}</p>`

Comment: You can also use the mark_safe decorator to simplify the template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Answer (score 2):

Another way, depending on needs is using a templatetag:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from markdownx.utils import markdownify

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def formatted_markdown(text):
    return mark_safe(markdownify(text))
```

and use it like

```
{{ article.text|formatted_markdown }}
```

Comment: Since it's a formatting issue I think that using a templatetag is the best solution