# How to use django-markdownx in my view in similar way to admin?

Tags: django

I'm stuck using django-markdownx to automatically update page and to submit changes.

I followed [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416123/i-cant-understand-the-django-markdownxs-usage) and managed to get django-markdownx working in admin, and within my view.  However in my view editing the textarea does not automatically update the page.

The admin page with django-markdownx is exactly what I want, updating the textarea updates the page, but not the underlying database field until you hit save.

So I then tried to rip out the admin code into my own view.

In my view/template I have a form, textarea similar to admin one.  I also included "/static/markdownx/js/markdownx.js" and set my form to mostly be similar to the admin page:

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="markdownx">
    <textarea name="myfield" rows="10" cols="40" required="" data-markdownx-upload-urls-path="/markdownx/upload/" data-markdownx-editor-resizable="" class="markdownx-editor" id="id_myfield" data-markdownx-urls-path="/markdownx/markdownify/" data-markdownx-latency="500" data-markdownx-init="" style="transition: opacity 1s ease;">
        {{ note.myfield }}
    </textarea>
</div>
<div class="markdownx-preview">
    {{ note.formatted_markdown|safe }}
</div>
</form>
```

This didn't work.

I see periodically there is requests to /markdownx/markdownify/ when you edit in admin, but not mine.  I'm not sure if I should aim to do the same or just do some timed javascript page refresh and pass all the data from within my form back to my view to then re-render the page again.

I can't quite get my head around the django-markdownx documentation.

UPDATE:

The Documentation [seems to suggest](http://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/js/docs/markdownx.html#MarkdownX) that a call to MarkdownX() should do the initialisation.

```
<script src="/static/markdownx/js/markdownx.js"></script> 
...
<script type="text/javascript">
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName('markdownx');
let md = new MarkdownX( element, element.querySelector('.markdownx-editor'), element.querySelector('.markdownx-preview'));
</script>
```

But when I try this I get.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkdownX is not defined
```

Also I don't see any initialisation like this within the admin page.

Is there an example of using the django-markdownx in your own views similar to the usage within admin?

Thanks

LB

Comment: Did you include `form.media` in your template?`

Comment: @Inquilabi I am getting same `Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkdownX is not defined` error when initialisation of second editor. Although, my first editor works fine. How to get multiple editors on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a broken solution.

The correct method would be to use the MarkdownX's built-in Javascript, but I just can't get it to work, yet.  So, I wrote my own.  It may be of use to others.

In template html, include js.cookie.min.js in order to get the django csrftoken.  Then a callback function which will be called when a change is made to the textarea.  We then update the preview div with HTML code we received back from MarkdownX's markdownify call.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myMDFunc( elem ) {
  input = elem.value;
  var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/markdownx/markdownify/",
      data: { CSRF: csrftoken, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, content: input}
    })
    .done(function(data, status){
      document.getElementById("markdownx-preview").innerHTML = data;
    });
} 
</script>
```

Still in the template html, in the form, call this function both for onchange and onkeyup.

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ note.title }}
  <div class="markdownx">
    <textarea onchange="myMDFunc(this)" onkeyup="myMDFunc(this)" cols="60" rows="5" name="text" >
      {{ note.myfield }}
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="markdownx-preview" id="markdownx-preview">
    {{ note.formatted_markdown|safe }}
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

In summary, a change to the textarea means we invoke the 'onchange' or 'onkeyup', which calls myMDFunc.  Then myMDFunc does an ajax call with data which is the raw MarkDown code, the response to this call is the pretty HTML data.  The callback within myMDFunc updates the preview with that pretty HTML.

It kinda works.  I'm sure the real MarkdownX code will handle drag'n'drop of images and pacing the ajax calls to be nice to the server.